# Excel SUMIF Advice

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I was hoping you might be able to help. I'm collected data in excel from a data source. The data source has 3 headings

```
Active,Occurrence,Time (seconds)

TRUE,    1, 0 
TRUE, 1, 12 
FALSE, 1, 12 
TRUE, 2, 12 
TRUE, 2, 16 
FALSE, 2, 16
```

The above relates to a machine which is either Active or Not. When it is active the "Occurrence" number will increment and start a timer. What I'm trying to do is to count the "Time" that this machine is TRUE relating to the specific incremented Occurrence.

E.g.
Occurrence 1 = 12 seconds 
Occurrence 2 = 4 seconds (16 - 12)

Edited 
In the sample data which I'm currently seeing I see the following:

### Time, Active, Occurrence, Time

11/09/14 12:13:48, FALSE, 6, 236 
11/09/14 12:53:48, TRUE,  7, 236 
11/09/14 12:53:49, TRUE,  7, 237 
11/09/14 12:53:55, TRUE,  7, 243 
11/09/14 12:53:57, TRUE,  7, 245 
11/09/14 12:53:58, FALSE, 7, 245

So on and so on.

What I'm hoping to do is for a specific Occurrence (i.e. 7) I can subtract the last number from the first number to get the total time the machine was ACTIVE. So in the example above 9 seconds.

Hope this makes sense.

Comment: So when a machine starts, it gets a `TRUE` with the starting time. And when it turns off it gets a `TRUE` with the ending time, and a `FALSE` with the ending time. And this ending time is the next `TRUE` time value? And then the occurrence increments by 1?

Answer (score 0):

If the format is always that the Occurence has a string of TRUE values, which is finally terminated by a FALSE. Then you could use a pivot table to do the heavy lifting.

In the screenshot below I have created a pivot table with the Occurence in the Rows, Active in the Columns, and the Min(Time) in the values. To do the Min(Time) just add the Time into the Values of the pivot, then right click on it in the pivot table and choose Summarize As>>Min

I have then added a new formula at the end of the pivot table to subtract the TRUE column form the FALSE column to get the difference between them.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to add a few worker columns to get what you are looking for - e.g. :

```
=SUMPRODUCT(($C$2:$C$25=C2)*($D$2:$D$25>D2))+1
```

[image: 1]

```
=COUNTIF($C$2:$C$25,"="&C2)-SUMPRODUCT(($C$2:$C$25=C2)*($D$2:$D$25>D2))
```

[image: 2]

```
=SUMPRODUCT(($C$2:$C$25=C2)*($F$2:$F$25=1)*($D$2:$D$25))
```

[image: 3]

```
=SUMPRODUCT(($C$2:$C$25=C2)*($E$2:$E$25=1)*($D$2:$D$25))
```

[image: 4]

```
=H2-G2
```

[image: 5]

I made the assumption that your times might not necessarily be in order - otherwise we could simplify this solution a bit.